# How to supply object to thunk in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, thunk

### There is an example here with a single property - "message" - supplied to thunk:

https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript

```js
// src/thunks.ts

import { Action } from 'redux'
import { sendMessage } from './store/chat/actions'
import { RootState } from './store'
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'

export const thunkSendMessage = (
  message: string
): ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, Action<string>> => async dispatch => {
  const asyncResp = await exampleAPI()
  dispatch(
    sendMessage({
      message,
      user: asyncResp,
      timestamp: new Date().getTime()
    })
  )
}

function exampleAPI() {
  return Promise.resolve('Async Chat Bot')
}
```

### How to write the same example but supplying an object - "{message}"

```js
// src/thunks.ts

import { Action } from 'redux'
import { sendMessage } from './store/chat/actions'
import { RootState } from './store'
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'

export const thunkSendMessage = ({
  message: string
}): ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, Action<string>> => async dispatch => {
  const asyncResp = await exampleAPI()
  dispatch(
    sendMessage({
      message,
      user: asyncResp,
      timestamp: new Date().getTime()
    })
  )
}

function exampleAPI() {
  return Promise.resolve('Async Chat Bot')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of ES6, you just have to remove data-type (string) from message object parameter.

```
// src/thunks.ts

import { Action } from 'redux'
import { sendMessage } from './store/chat/actions'
import { RootState } from './store'
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'

interface Message {
messageText : string,
//...other properties if required ...
}

export const thunkSendMessage = (
  message : Message
): ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, Action<string>> => async dispatch => {
  const asyncResp = await exampleAPI()
  dispatch(
    sendMessage({
      message: message.messageText,
      user: asyncResp,
      timestamp: new Date().getTime()
    })
  )
}

function exampleAPI() {
  return Promise.resolve('Async Chat Bot')
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for an answer which qualifies as typescript.

Comment: how to then export that shape to a function component: eg:const myComponent = ({thunkSendMessage:whatTypeHere}) => ()

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've posted a response above to understand the problem better -

Answer (score 0):

ok I have created an example to make it easier to understand the problem.

#### actions.tsx - this seems to pass - (thankyou MuhhammadUmarFarooq - for your answer to my question.)

```js
import {RootState} from 'src/index';
import { Action } from 'redux'
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk';
import { actionTypes as at } from './actionTypes';

type shapePayload = {
  message: string
};

const acExample = (
  payload: shapePayload
): ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, Action<string>> => dispatch => {
  const {message} = payload;
  return dispatch({
    type: at.AC_TYPE_EXAMPLE,
    payload: {
      message,
      somethingelse: true
    }
  });
}

export type shapeExample = ReturnType<typeof acExample>;

export {
  acExample
};
```

#### component using action creator - This is the problem here:

```js
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {shapeExample, acExample} from 'src/store/examples/actions';

type shape = {
  acExample: shapeExample
}
const myComponent:FC<shape> = ({acExample}) => (
  <button onClick={() => {
    acExample({message: 'cheese'});
  }} >
    trigger store update
  </button>
);

export default connect(
  () => ({}),
  {
    acExample
  }
)(myComponent);
```

- Error - acExample :
  Expected 3 arguments
- Error - (myComponent):

TypeScript  Argument of type 'FC' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<{ acExample: (payload: shapePayload) => void; }, shape>>'. Type 'FunctionComponent' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<Matching<{ acExample: (payload: shapePayload) => void; }, shape>>'. Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible. Type 'WeakValidationMap | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<Matching<{ acExample: (payload: shapePayload) => void; }, shape>> | undefined'. Type 'WeakValidationMap' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<Matching<{ acExample: (payload: shapePayload) => void; }, shape>>'. Types of property 'acExample' are incompatible. Type 'Validator<ThunkAction<void, any, unknown, Action>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Validator<(payload: shapePayload) => void> | undefined'. Type 'Validator<ThunkAction<void, any, unknown, Action>>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<(payload: shapePayload) => void>'. Type 'ThunkAction<void, any, unknown, Action>' is not assignable to type '(payload: shapePayload) => void

Comment: Please add question details to the question with some heading like Update... So that other people can answer as well